Nested Interface Projections in Spring Data JPA
I am working on a spring boot based application where I want to utilize interface based projection as I want to select partial column from my mysql database.
I have a CourseEntity.java class with a One-To-Many relationship with ModuleEntity.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CourseEntity extends BaseEntity {

  private String title;
  private String subTitle;
  private String longDescription;
  private String shortDescription;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<ModuleEntity> modules = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
  ...
  ...
  // 100 More Fields
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "module")
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ModuleEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Long id;

  private String name;
  private String shortDescription;
  private String longDescription;
  private String thumbnailPath;

  @Column(name = "course_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long courseId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", updatable = false)
  private CourseEntity course;
  ...
  ...
  // 50 more fields
}

There are many fields in my class as you can see 100 in course table and 50 in module table. There are even columns with datatype as JSON which contains huge amount of static data only. I want to create a simple API that should only return course id, title, sub_title including module's data containing only module id name. For this api, I don't want to select whole course and module entity because there will be lot of data transfer over the network which is not being used.
For that I have created 2 interface for projection purposes
public interface CourseLookup {
    Long getId();
    String getTitle();
    String getSubTitle();
    List<ModuleLookup> getModules();
}

public interface ModuleLookup {

    Long getId();
    String getName();
}

Now I dont know how to map the module related data to "getModules()" method. In JPQL I am unable to use aliases for modules. When I try to use the following query, I get getModules() as null
@Query("Select distinct c.id as id, c.title as title, c.subTitle as subTitle, m.id as moduleId, m.name as moduleName From CourseEntity Left Join c.modules m Where id = :id")
Optional<CourseLookup> getData(Long id);

When I try to map using alias like this, then hibernate selects all columns from the database for module
@Query("Select distinct c.id as id, c.title as title, c.subTitle as subTitle, m as modules From CourseEntity Left Join c.modules m Where id = :id")
Optional<CourseLookup> getData(Long id);

Also when using the second approach, I am getting duplicate records despite using the distinct keyword. I am unable to map nested projections

Some ideas (no IDEA/DB available):

I would be extra clear and write .... c.id = :id.
About your second query: Where are duplicates, in modules? Try distinct on m.id.


Try taking a look at my library, it might be right for you. Through jpa-search-helper you can, in addition to building dynamic and advanced queries, apply the projection of only the fields you want.
All based on JPA entities (and nested entities)
